# Ошибка 404 при запросе локального сайта на Python

Tags: python, html, webview, request, site

Помогите решить проблему с запуском сайта в среде tkinter на Python. Ситуация заключается в следующем, есть написанный сайт с материалами для сотрудников, который можно открывать оффлайн запуская его из папки. При запуске приложения и открытии его в IDE PyCharm сайт работает, он его находит и всё открывает, однако - когда я компилирую всё в exe для переноса на рабочий компьютер, он отказывается запускать сайт и выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error: 404 Not Found
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:4291/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%A1.html' caused an error:

File does not exist.
```

Код с библиотекой которую использую, следующий:

```
import webview

class Site():
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Frame(frame2, highlightbackground='#707070',
                         highlightthickness=1)
        self.bottom = Frame(frame2, background="white",
                            highlightbackground='#707070',
                            highlightthickness=1)
        self.top.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True, pady=[2, 0])
        self.btn_site = ttk.Button(frame2, text='Запустить сайт',
                                   compound='left',
                                   image=image_site,
                                   command=self.site, cursor='hand2')
        self.text_title = ttk.Label(frame2, text='Необходимо запустить '
                                                 'сайт '
                                                 'для '
                                                 'просмотра...',
                                    font=('Times New Roman', 16, 'bold'),
                                    justify="center", background="white")

        self.btn_site.pack(in_=self.top, side=RIGHT)
        self.text_title.pack(in_=self.bottom, side=TOP, pady=275)

    def site(self):
        webview.create_window('Сайт',
                              'site/Website Main.html',
                              width=1274,
                              height=725, x=325, y=236,
                              on_top=True, zoomable=True,
                              text_select=True, frameless=True,
                              easy_drag=False)
        webview.start()
```

С реальным сайтом, который доступен в Интернете всё в порядке exe его открывает, локальный в упор не хочет.
Подскажите, что минимального исправить, чтобы ситуация изменилась. Буду благодарен!